# Observing tensorflow rnn model weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, machine-translation

I am using tensorflow rnn translation model published here:
[translation model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate)

I want to make changes in part of this code according to my own ideas.
First thing I wanna do is to see the `target_weights` in each layer.
What I know is that at first an array of `target_weights` which contains zeros for padding and 1 for each word in a sentence.
After initialization it is fed to a session.run method and it will change surely.
Now I want to know whether any one knows how should I see the change this array face during the learning process.
Or something else, how can I see each layer weights and check the values corresponding to each layer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably **[TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html)**, which gives you ability to visualize arbitrary values/statistics of your network.

[image: tensorboard]

All you have to do is to add `summarizers` in your code, for example through

```
tf.scalar_summary("norm of weights going", norm_of_weights)
```

and later on create summary writer

```
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("logs_directory/", sess.graph_def)
```

Which will create your logs, which you can analyze through tensorboard.
The way you define summaries, which things you log etc. is up to you and depends solely on the problem. Do you want to track each weight separately? If so - add scalar summaries to each of these. You want just a brief evolution? Focus on norms of these. You can also monitor histograms (so the distribution of activations for example) through `tf.histogram_summary` and so on.

Comment: thanks a lot. infact I want to check weights at the first step and then compare it to the something else I need to have this array's real values in my code. what should I add to my code ?